# Shell script to build executable from node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, dockerfile

I'm trying ompile archive `node.js` executable into one executable using [node-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/node-packer).
For my all packages, executables of `node.js` are in `{projectRoot}/node_modedules/.bin`

The project structure as follow:

```
|- node_modules
|   |-- .bin
|       |--- executable with source code 
|- compiled-bin
|   |-- compiled executable
```

I wrote a shell script to do it.
 Hope you can review it:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filepath in ./node_modules/.bin/*; do
    export baseName="${filepath##*/}"
    nodec $filepath --clean-tmpdir --make-args=-j10 --output=./compile-bin/$baseName.out  
    chmod +x ./compile-bin/$baseName.out 
done
```

This is dockerfile, I used to run the above script in container:

```
FROM node:8.3.0 as package

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  python \
  make \
  squashfs-tools \
  gcc \
  g++ \
  clang-3.5 \
  clang++-3.5

# Install nodec compiler
RUN curl -L http://enclose.io/nodec/nodec-linux-x64.gz | gunzip > /usr/local/bin/nodec
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/nodec

# Install npm packages
RUN npm i --no-optional \
  && ls -lh 

# Run build scripts
RUN mkdir compile-bin \
  && chmod +x ./build-script \
  && sync \
  && ./build-script
```

Answer (score 1):

The shellscript you have seems simple enough. It looks fairly nice, though the use of `export` is unnecessary.

The dockerfile is a bit of a different story.
It's not fully clear whether you intend to use the built application from within the docker container you are setting up there or whether the container is only used to build the executables that are later moved elsewhere.

For now I am assuming that the docker container you create there is the final artifact, and I highly recommend looking into multi-stage builds to slim down the final result.

In addition to that, it feels quite peculiar to install **four** different C/C++ compilers. It could make sense to separate the dependencies of your application into two categories and keep a `package_list` (and `make_package_list`) that can be used to set up the application.
This dovetails nicely with my next suggestion: Make use of docker's caching mechanism.

Currently this Docker container will be rebuilt from scratch **every single codechange**. That is because you are first `COPY`ing all the source files into the container.
Instead of doing that, you want to take advantage of caching and perform steps that rarely change first:

```
FROM node:8.3.0 AS package

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update

# install building time dependencies
COPY make_package_list .
RUN make_package_list > xargs apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends
# install nodec compiler
RUN curl -L http://enclose.io/nodec/nodec-linux-x64.gz | gunzip > /usr/local/bin/nodec
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/nodec

# install runtime dependencies
COPY package_list .
RUN package_list > xargs apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends

# NOW we copy the source files and start the build process
COPY . .
RUN npm i --no-optional \
  && ls -lh

# Run build scripts
RUN mkdir compile-bin \
  && chmod +x ./build-script \
  && sync \
  && ./build-script
```

This setup should make the build a bit quicker after the first run, so long as none of the dependencies for your application change. That does not work for the npm-dependencies, though.

It would be possible to change that, too (by copying the package-lock and running `npm -i` before copying the remainder of the source files), but since you are copying the complete local directory, the current script will use your local package-cache.
While that will be a faster build, it can introduce subtle issues with stale packages and will take a smidge more time during the `COPY` operation.

Comment: You probably want to `apt-get update` after `COPY package_list`, for times when the previous layer is cached but the source archives have changed.  I usually write a single `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install && apt-get clean`, to avoid layer bloat.

Answer (score 1):

This script doesn't need Bash.  Plain POSIX shell should be fine.

It's probably a good idea to set `-e` and `-u` shell flags to ensure we exit with a failure status if any of the commands fail.

Does `baseName` really need exporting in the environment?  It looks as if a plain variable should be fine.  The quotes don't add anything in this context.  Perhaps include the target path (though we can drop the redundant initial `./`), to avoid repeating that for the two subsequent expansions.

Do remember to quote expansions of variables, particularly those that come from filename globs.

---

## Improved code

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

for filepath in node_modules/.bin/*
do
    outFile=compile-bin/${filepath##*/}
    nodec "$filepath" --clean-tmpdir --make-args=-j10 --output="$outFile" 
    chmod +x "$outFile"
done
```

---

Perhaps instead of `chmod +x ./build-script && ./build-script` we could simply `sh build-script`.

---

As mentioned in the other answer, copying the whole working directory as first layer will cause everything subsequent to be built each time.  But we probably don't want to *copy* our sources into the image.  It's generally better to volume-mount into the container, so the run command becomes:

```sh
docker run -v "$(pwd):/usr/src/app" $build_image sh build-script
```

Then you can use the build image many times, compiling different versions of your code as needed.